# Internal Gas Heaters

Tags: gas, heat

My property has no LP gas currently. I am converting an out building and need heat in several of the rooms. Can I run a gas line along the horseshoe shaped inside wall that is a common wall to all the rooms and have 5 split offs from the main line in?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. All we could answer would be "maybe", unless you add more info (e.g. a dimensioned diagram, with pipe sizes).

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to ask .... of course you can run the gas line .... but, is that really what you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

The flexible gas line is readily available to carry the gas.  The critical point is that it is sized properly to carry the load.  An under sized line will create a hazardous situation.